# Problem in slideDown() and slideUp() effect in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want a slidedown and slideup effect on a particular div when you hove  on corresponding `<li>` tag. You can check it live at this link http://mashup2.sunnydsouza.com/index3.php

Am using the following jQuery to solve it

```
$(".altbgcolor").mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).css("background-   color","#D3EAC7").find(".newsthumb").corner();
                $(".newstext h1",this).css("color","#000");
                $(".newstext div",this).css("color","#000"); 
                $(".sharedp").slideDown(slow);

            }).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color","#f5f5f5").find(".newsthumb").corner();
                $(".altbgcolor:even").css("background-color","#f0f0f0");
                $(".newstext h1",this).css("color","#666666");
                $(".newstext div",this).css("color","#666666"); 
                $(".sharedp").slideUp(slow);
            });
```

Am I doing something wrong. Can someone just check the site html and see where am going wrong. I am in this big dilemna here :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the slow in quotes..

```
$(".sharedp").slideDown('slow');
```

and

```
$(".sharedp").slideUp('slow');
```

---

**Update**

To limit the slideUp/Down to the next `.sharedp` element use

```
$(".altbgcolor").mouseenter(function() {
                $(this).css("background-color","#D3EAC7").find(".newsthumb");
                $(".newstext h1",this).css("color","#000");
                $(".newstext div",this).css("color","#000"); 
                $(this).next(".sharedp").slideDown('slow');

            }).mouseleave(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color","#f5f5f5").find(".newsthumb");
                $(".altbgcolor:even").css("background-color","#f0f0f0");
                $(".newstext h1",this).css("color","#666666");
                $(".newstext div",this).css("color","#666666"); 
                $(this).next(".sharedp").slideUp('slow');
            });
```

You will notice that i have removed the `.corner` method which seemed to be causing a silent failure of the script...

Also it would be better in terms of speed and maintenance if you created classes that describe the styling you want, and just used jquery to add/remove these classes..

---

*Some of the **Errors** found*

- `title="Traffic Exchange""` should have a single ending `"`
- ID's of elements that are numeric. Only HTML5 allows for numeric IDs, otherwise look at the specs http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2
- duplicate IDs. IDs should be unique in the document.
- `<div class="newsthumb" center center no-repeat;">` the `center center no-repeat;"` should not be there
- You have `div` elements under a `ul` which is invalid. Only `li` and other `ul` elements can go under a `ul`, there rest should be *inside* the `li`.

and more.. in general you should strive for valid html. 
Validators can help you, such as http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmashup2.sunnydsouza.com%2Findex3.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=1&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

Comment: Thanks but it doesnt solve the problem :( Could u check the html code of the site please. I cant copy paste that huge a code...

Comment: only the adjoining one to the li tag. As and when you hover the next li their corresponding .sharedp should slideup or down              EDIT:  it doesnt seem to be working :( even if i use simple show() or hide()

Comment: Thanks Gaby, but still it isnt showing the effect. should i hide the <div class="sharedp"> tag initially or what?

Comment: It does cause significant delay in jQuery to load. You are right. But how to create this effect in css?

Comment: please gaby can u help me out with this?

Comment: @Sunny, that page is full of invalid html. *wrong nesting*, *bad quoting* etc.. I have also updated the code due to a syntax error so you should re-take it.. The way i would do it, though , is http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zzj7E/2/ Added new css rules and simpler jquery code..

Comment: Thanks a lot. Am really grateful you went all the way into the code to check the problem. Appreciate it. However could you mention what changes you did apart from adding css and jquery. Did you make any changes in the html too. Because you mentioned about wrong nesting,bad quoting...these terms are new to me  and so I would like to know where I went wrong. There is a lot to learn from experts like you and stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Also, another small help needed. Currently when you hover over each newslist the div slides down. I am gona place buttons on that div. But currently user cant hover over the div since as soon as it is out of .newslist the div slides up. How do i work around this ? :(

Comment: @Sunny, for the issue of the `.shared` closing when you move out of the `li`, i would put it inside the `li` with a white background. This way you solve one of the *errors* in your html that i mention and also fix this issue, with the *mouseout* since the mouse will remain inside the `li` even when it is over the `.sharedp`.

Comment: I have added the <div class=.sharedp> inside the <li>, but it doesnt seem to work yet. Should there be a change in jQuery? I even removed the '.next' in the jQuery since we are bindin it in single element. But still it doesnt work

Comment: @sunny, instead of `.next` use `.find` since we are at the `li` and want to go to the `<div class="sharedp">` inside it..

Comment: thanks a lot. works like a charm. But the white background thing....it would be good if i could maintain a nice border around the block so that it gives the same effect as when the div was outside <li> tag. any suggestions?

Comment: @SUnny.. give `margin: 5px -5px -5px -5px;` to the `.sharedp` http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/zzj7E/5/ And we should wrap this question up. The main issues have been resolved. For newer thing please post new questions..

Comment: yeah..thanks a lot again. This post has been marked answered.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $(".sharedp").slideUp("slow");.
```

slow should be a string

Comment: Thanks but it didnt solve the problem. Could u check the html code of the webpage please...might help in troubleshooting the problem

Answer (score 1):

If that is a direct copy of the code, you need to put "**slow**" in quotes in the slideUp/down functions.

Comment: it didnt solve the problem. Thanks though. Could u check the html code of the webpage please...might help in troubleshooting the problem